# Advice Needed with Mysql Query, sorting, grouping and performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 'message' table, where users send and receive messages, pretty straight forward. What I would like to do is: retrieve DISTINCT sender_ids WHERE receiver_id is X, and have it sorted in a way where users from who receiver X has unread mesages appear first and users from who receiver X has read messages appear after and everything is sorted by created_at DESC.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Note: Performance is an issue too.

This is the query I was using, but it appears that sorting isn't really done right, maybe DISTINCT screws things up? I am expecting result 6, 5, 4, 2, 3 - but am getting 6, 5, 4, 3, 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT sender_id
FROM message m
WHERE receiver_id = 1
ORDER BY read_at, created_at DESC
```

Here is the table with sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `receiver_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `message` text,
  `read_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sender` (`sender_id`),
  KEY `receiver` (`receiver_id`),
  KEY `dates` (`receiver_id`,`read_at`,`created_at`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `message` (id, sender_id, receiver_id, message, read_at, created_at)
VALUES 
  (1,2,1,NULL,'2011-01-01 01:01:01','2011-01-01 01:01:01'),
  (2,1,2,NULL,'2011-01-01 01:01:01','2011-01-01 01:01:02'),
  (3,2,1,NULL,'2011-01-01 01:01:01','2011-01-01 01:01:03'),
  (4,3,1,NULL,'2011-01-01 01:01:01','2011-01-01 01:01:04'),
  (5,3,1,NULL,'2011-01-01 01:01:01','2011-01-01 01:01:05'),
  (6,1,4,NULL,'2011-01-01 01:01:01','2011-01-01 01:01:06'),
  (7,4,1,NULL,NULL,'2011-01-01 01:01:07'),
  (8,5,1,NULL,NULL,'2011-01-01 01:01:08'),
  (9,5,1,NULL,NULL,'2011-01-01 01:01:09'),
  (10,1,6,NULL,NULL,'2011-01-01 01:01:10'),
  (11,6,1,NULL,NULL,'2011-01-01 01:01:11');
```

Comment: The tricky situation is when there are both unread and read messages from the same user, and making sure the sender is placed into the first group rather than the second.

Comment: When there are multiple messages from a sender, which `created_at` do you want to use for sorting, the most recent or the oldest?

Comment: @outis, I want the most recent for created_at. Your solution in the reply below works, I am wondering if there is anything I can do to improve performance though, I fear that there will be many messages between many different sender/receivers.

Comment: @BugBusterX: the first thing to do is test the query. There's no point in making it more performant if it's not necessary. Note that making it perform faster will be quite tricky. You could do it by creating an additional table storing the data to sort by and relying on an index on that table, but it will be at the expense of increased insertion time and introduce potential integrity problems.

Comment: ... Also, Tricker's suggestion of moving variable-length columns to an ancillary table may also help, as it can speed up row access (this is less noticeable when an index is used).

Comment: @outis: so if I do have an index on receiver_id, it would not make much sense to move the variable length field out into a different table right?

Comment: @BugBusterX: my gut says it wouldn't, but it's better to rely on testing. Ancillary tables for variable length columns are generally for improving queries at-large, rather than specific ones. Note that having an index on `receiver_id` isn't enough; a query must be able to use this index to avoid penalties from dynamic row sizes.

Comment: ... Note also that the table engine type matters. If you were using [InnoDB tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-physical-record.html), moving the columns [wouldn't be beneficial to speed](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=377652&seqNum=3). Read about [MyISAM table storage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-table-formats.html) and [variable length columns in InnoDB tables](http://www.mysqlsystems.com/manual/innodb10en/innodb-row-format.html) for the nitty-gritty.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @outis, I'm using InnoDB at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following returns the desired result on the sample data:

```
SELECT sender_id
  FROM message AS m
  WHERE receiver_id=?
  GROUP BY sender_id
  ORDER BY COUNT(*)=COUNT(read_at), MAX(created_at) DESC;
```

If you want to use the oldest message when sorting by `created_at`, change `MAX` to `MIN`.

`COUNT(read_at)` ignores nulls, while `COUNT(*)` doesn't, so the two will be unequal if there are any unread messages. If there aren't too many messages to a giver receiver, it should perform fairly quickly (the index on `receiver_id` will help). Profile the query before deciding more optimization is needed.

With a bit of tweaking, The Scrum Meister's aggregate expression can be made to work. Try `MIN(IF(read_at IS NULL, 0, 1))` as a replacement for `COUNT(*)=COUNT(read_at)`. I don't think it will improve execution time, but there's at least a small chance it will (like much of optimization, it depends on MySQL internals).

Result of EXPLAIN on the test table:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys  | key      | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | ref  | receiver,dates | receiver | 8       | const |    7 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Getting rid of the aggregate functions applied to the `message` rows:

```
SELECT sender_id
  FROM ( (SELECT sender_id, 0 AS all_read, MAX(created_at) AS recent
          FROM message AS m
          WHERE receiver_id=:receiver AND read_at IS NULL
          GROUP BY sender_id)
       UNION
         (SELECT sender_id, 1 AS all_read, MAX(created_at) AS recent
          FROM message AS m
          WHERE receiver_id=:receiver AND read_at IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY sender_id)
       ) AS t
  GROUP BY sender_id
  ORDER BY MIN(all_read), recent DESC;
```

look to lose ground. This query works by using constant values (the separate queries allows for this) for the column indicating whether or not any of the sender's messages are unread, rather than the aggregate expressions. Here's the [output of `EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html) for this query:

```
+----+--------------+------------+-------+----------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table      | type  | possible_keys  | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+----------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL           | NULL  | NULL    | NULL |    5 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  2 | DERIVED      | m          | ref   | receiver,dates | dates | 17      |      |    4 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  3 | UNION        | m          | range | receiver,dates | dates | 17      | NULL |    3 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|NULL| UNION RESULT | <union2,3> | ALL   | NULL           | NULL  | NULL    | NULL | NULL |                                              |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+----------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This query appears to be doing exactly what I need, I just wonder if there is a way to do the same more effectively, since there are going to be a lot of messages back and forth between users. Is there an alternative method I should look into? By the way, what would be a factor in slow performance: many senders or many messages per sender? or both?

Comment: @BugBusterX: A little bit of both. The former (many senders) you can't do much about. Many senders will have its biggest impact on the sort itself (as it means more rows in the result table to sort), which will also be true of other queries. Many messages per sender will affect calculating the aggregate statistics used in the sort (moving this to a result column may or may not help, depending on how MySQL handles it internally).

Comment: WOW, thank you so much for all your help! I really appreciate all the time you've spent helping me out! I will test the second version of the query once I load more test data to see which is faster. Again, thank you very much for all your effort, you are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

How about a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT sender_id
FROM message m
WHERE receiver_id = 1
GROUP BY sender_id
ORDER BY MAX(IFNULL(read_at,'9999-01-01')) DESC
```

Comment: It does not sort by created by ASC (I added it) and I'm not sure if this would be best performance-wise.

Comment: Still, +1 for grouping and aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

First a little table optimalisation in the way i should do it:

```
create table messages
(
    message_id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    sender_id begint unsigned not null,
    receiver_id bigint unsigned not null,
    read_at datetime default null,
    created_at datetime
) engine=innodb;

create table message_body
(
    message_id bigint unsigned not null,
    message varchar(32000) not null
) engine=innodb;
```

i use a varchar instead off a text, because when you have a small message in a text field you will 2 bytes.
And a message will sometimes have less then 255 chars so then u will store only 1 byte instead off 2.
watch [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html).

So there is not as much weight for load a row, if your messages are not in the same table. and if you going to get A LOTS off data it will be very usefull!

My Query u ask for would look like this:

```
select distinct(sender_id) 
from messages
where receiver_id = x
group by sender_id
order by read_at desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the "everything is sorted by created_at desc" part.

If the unread messages should appear first, then you cannot sort "everything" by created_at.

But if you mean to first list all unread messages (sorted by created_at), then list all read messages (again sorted by created_at) then the following will do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM message m
WHERE receiver_id = 1
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
      WHEN read_at IS NULL THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END ASC,
    created_at DESC;
```

This generates a slightly different order than you expect, but looking at the sample data I think it should be correct.

Comment: yes I meant to say "first list all unread messages (sorted by created_at), then list all read messages (again sorted by created_at)"  Suggestion from @outis works, yours will to when I add MAX(created_at) and group by sender_id, but I'm concerned about performance, since there will be lot of messages between a lot of users.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I overlooked the requirement to do a grouping by sender